# High pitched microphone noise

Tags: microphone

My internal and external (usb) microphone give me a high pitched noise, it's as if the recorded sound gets in a unlimited loop and then disappears.

Could anyone help me fix this? I've an Acer Extensa 2510J (ALC283).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your speakers on when this happens? If so, it's called [feedback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_feedback). Try to lower the volume or turn off the speakers.

Comment: Yes they're on because I would like to use Skype on this laptop. Therefore it's not possible lowering the volume or to turn off the speakers, right?